# Redmine - Stop notification - Shady Mode not work

Tags: ruby, redmine

i have a server installation of redmine, i have installed shady mode plugin with 3.4 version and it is working but now i have update to 4.1 and doesn't work. This plugin allow me to enable shady mode and stop sending notification.

I found the problem of plugin code, I found two files where in both it does the check to see if the mode is active by going to retrieve the user's properties, in one file the check actually works and the condition returns the correct value, in the other file (the one that decides if to actually send the email or not) this setting is always false (or null).

I guess with the new version of redmine the plugin in that piece of code can't find the variables.

this is the file that work `hook.rb`:

```
module RedmineShady 
  module Hook
    class ViewListener < Redmine::Hook::ViewListener
      # necessary for using content_tag in Listener
      attr_accessor :output_buffer
      # If shady, show message on the top
      def view_layouts_base_html_head(context = {})
        session = context[:controller].session
 
        if User.current.pref[:shady]
          style = 'margin: 0; padding: 10px; border-width: 0 0 2px; background-image: none'
 
          content_tag :div, id: 'shady-bar', class: 'flash error', style: style do
            concat link_to l(:button_cancel), { controller: 'shady', action: 'destroy' },
                           method: :delete, style: 'float: right'
            concat l(:notice_shady_mode)
          end
        end
      end
    end 
  end 
end
```

and this is the file that doesn't work: `mail_interceptor.rb`

```
module RedmineShady
  class MailInterceptor
    def self.delivering_email(message)
 
      message.perform_deliveries = false if User.current.pref[:shady]
    end
  end
end
```

Why does `User.current.pref[:shady]` work in `hook.rb` but not in `mail_interceptor.rb`?

Answer (score 0):

Between Redmine 3.4 and Redmine 4.1, the way how email notifications are send has [changed significantly](https://www.redmine.org/issues/26791).

Specifically, Redmine now renders and sends notification mails in the background rather than waiting in the update request. Also, a unique mail is now rendered for each recipient. While rendering the mail, `User.current` will be set to the respective recipient (rather than the sending user as in Redmine 3.4).

As such, the plugin needs to be updated for Redmine 4.1 and likely needs a significant re-architecture due to those Redmine changes.